# How to write chain functions DART?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm writing the flutter application and need a chain function. I found some solutions but it didn't work for me. How it's written?

For example.(i written custom get function)

```swift
 get().addHeader(value:xx).addHeader(value:xxx)
```

I'm using HTTP helper or String helper functions.

Comment: use `..` =  `get()..addHeader(value:xx)..addHeader(value:xxx)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As adviced in [Effective Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart):

> AVOID returning `this` from methods just to enable a fluent interface.

Method cascades are a better solution for chaining method calls.

In your case

```
class HttpCall {
  void addHeader(String name, String value) { ... }
}

main() {
  // get() returns a HttpCall
  get()
    ..addHeader('name1', 'value1')
    ..addHeader('name2', 'value2');
}
```